nx:run-commands executor hangs after first command
I am trying to understand how to configure my project.json file. As a simple test, I have tried using the nx:run-commands executor, by adding the following to the "targets" section in my project.json file:
"test-output": {
    "executor": "nx:run-commands",
    "options": {
        "commands": [
            "echo 'SOMETHING NEW'",
            "echo 'TEST'",
            "exit"
        ],
        "parallel": false
    }
}

I would have expected this to output SOMETHING NEW, then TEST, and then maybe (not sure how that would be interpreted) close the console window, or nothing else might happen, as this is, essentially, the behaviour described in the documentation:

The commands option accepts as many commands as you want. (...) You can run them sequentially by setting parallel: false

Instead, when I run nx test-output, I just see 'SOMETHING NEW' ... and then it just hangs. Nothing else happens. The console cursor keeps blinking in the line below, but I can neither input anything nor stop the process with CtrlC.
If I run nx from within WebStorm, I see that the output is actually 'SOMETHING NEW' --watch - i.e., there is an additional --watch parameter, which I suspect may have to do with the failure to continue. However, I have no idea where this comes from or how to suppress it.
What am I doing wrong?
